# Footer bar not formatting correctly

Tags: html, css

So I am being thwarted by footers. At this early stage I am trying to get all of my footer to go along the bottom of the page but I am having no luck (see my HTML code at the bottom of this post).

To make the nav bars at the top and the bottom of the page my CSS looks like this:

```
.header {
  height: 30px;
}
.footer {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

And my ul's have this CSS, with the thought that they will line up on the bottom of the page:

```
.posRight li{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

.posLeft li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

But for some reason the second ul(class `posRight`) is sticking under my fist ul and I can't seem to move it unless I set the position to absolute and then manually move it over which is messy at the least.

Another thing I noticed was that my heading nav bar, which has the pos right class too, if I add the `float: right;` to the `header` class and not to the `posRight` class makes my central image(class `imgP`) jump off to one side rather than stay in the center??

It is centered by the following CSS:

```
.imgP {
 height: 231px; //specifying the class here works over specifying it on .logo which stretches it height ways 
}

.logo {
  width: 269px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 112px;
}
```

This is the rest of my HTML if it helps:

```
 <body>

    <!-- top navBar -->
  <div class="inLine posRight header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox">Gmail</a></li>
      <li>Anna</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- main content: search bar and google button -->
  <div id="content" class="mainContent">

    <div class="imgP">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo11w.png" alt="logo">
    </div>

     <form action="#">
       <input class="txtBox" type="text" />
       <div class="centreB"> 

            <input class="butt" type="submit" name="Google Search" value="Google Search" />

            <input class="choose" type="submit" name="Google Search" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" />
       </div>
     </form>
  </div>



  <!-- footer navBar -->
  <div class="footer">
   <ul class="posLeft">
     <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Busniness</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="posRight">
     <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li> 
   </ul>
```

```
</body>
```

I am sorry that if this question has become too long but these two things link together so I didn't feel that it was worth it to make two posts.

Comment: Would be great if you can create a fiddle so that it's easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry! Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anna6429/95f1hkuk/1/) of it :) I forgot to say that I am also using css with all of the custom styles reset (see the top of my css in the fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

footer** class as below i think i will work for you

```css
.footer {   
        position: fixed;  //updated
    bottom: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    line-height: 40px;
      min-width: 100%; //updated
      width: auto; //updated
}
```

here is the working js fiddle your solution

[Updated DEMO jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95f1hkuk/4/)

Comment: @Anna  please check out the answer

Comment: Hi Himesh, sorry for my slow response I have not had internet for the last day-groan! Than you for your code however, the min-width line looks correct in fiddle but on my laptop the footer bar stops short of the end of the wider pages- how can I make this bar fit to different page sizes?

Comment: @Anna and and demo fiddle as well

Comment: oh so I got it working by adding a `width:100%;` line above the min width line (ketp at `min-width:960px;`)so that the bottom line will fill the bottom of the page... in your fiddle it now looks like it did on my computer yesterday.. I had not played with making the position fixed so I will have a look at this :)
thank you for your replies!

Comment: @Anna if you get what you want from my replies you can upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to place image and form.
This may help you.

HTML code

```
<body>  
<!-- top navBar -->
<div class="posRyt">
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox">Gmail</a></li>
      <li>Anna</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<!-- main content: search bar and google button -->
<div id="content" class="mainContent">
    <div class="imgP">
        <img class="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
        <div class="iform">
            <form action="#">
                <input class="txtBox" type="text" />
                    <div class="centreB"> 
                    <input class="butt" type="submit" name="Google Search" value="Google Search" />
                    <input class="choose" type="submit" name="Google Search" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" />
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

<!-- footer navBar -->
    <div class="footer">
    <ul class="posLeft">
         <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Busniness</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       </ul>

       <ul class="posRight">
         <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li> 
       </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.posRyt{
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
.posRyt li{
display:inline-block;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.footer {

    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px; 
}
.footer li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.posRight {
    float: right;
}
ul.posLeft {
    float: left;
}
.iform {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 28px;
}
.imgP{
width:50%;
text-align:center;
}
```

For alignment preview check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0fptcwgz/4/)

Comment: I want the image dead in the centre with the form below it (the form being the 'search bar', and I am practicing my html and css skills on trying to re-create the google home page) see the fiddle I added above :)